# Estimote Stickers + Node.js + Raspberry-Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, estimote

I'm using Noble / Bleacon with a Raspberry-Pi and a MacbookProRetina and I'm trying to discover an Estimote Sticker but it's really difficult since it's broadcasting an iBeacon packet once every X minutes.

As far as I know somebody told me that it's broadcasting more other kind of packets (motion sensor, temperature) rather than the standard iBeacon packet.

Any chance that I can discover these stickers with my setup?

Comment: Hi did you get any updates on that subject ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the Estimote team told me it's in their roadmap to release a Node.js SDK ... I'll wait :(

Comment: Same for me since months ;-/

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm stuck trying to detect Estimote stickers from a raspi.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't work on this anymore but I wasn't able to detect them :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems not,

However you might be able to reverse engineer some of the packets, someone went into this a while back on Make:

http://makezine.com/2014/01/03/reverse-engineering-the-estimote/

Regards,
Vincent